# How can I continue using a web app while a file uploads from 1st screen?

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

I have a project that needs to upload a large file, while that file is uploading is it possible to progress through a series of other screens, to continue to obtain input from user, then once they get to the final screen, file is uploaded.

Anyone have a trick for something like this ? As i know the file upload happens within a form post/get.

Comment: Why not try to launch upload in a "popup" window, that won't stop you from continuing on your application. Other option is to make sure the pages are javascript and don't need to reload the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using an iframe, which simple links to a page with a form to post a file, once the user has selected a file and clicked upload/submit you can hide the iframe and progress into our areas... but things will get tricky where you need to handle errors, ie: incorrect file formats, zero byte files etc... maybe you can download the file and display any errors right at the end of your process/wizard input.